# mp4 videos on a wordpress site don't play on chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, mp4

I'm trying to show mp4-videos playlists on my wordpress website using the [playlist] shortcode, and they appear on all browsers but Chrome on desktop.
On Chrome, It shows up as an audio file, and opens as an audio file as well.
Here is an example: http://torah24-7.com/balak-h/ 
What can cause that?
 I have thousands of videos. Can I handle it with one-code for all vidoes? Or with bulk transcode?

Thank you very much

Comment: For me that page displays the same on Firefox and Chrome.  No video plays in either for me, Mac OS

Comment: My guess is that the problem is with your encoding... that you've encoded it into a video format that some browsers can't handle.

Answer (score -1):

While this does not quite address your problem, personally I'd go for hosting your video on a platform such as YouTube or Vimeo and then embedding that video into your webpage.

That way, Youtube/Vimeo takes care of all the encoding stuff and the bandwidth for displaying the video as well.

Reference: https://www.wp101.com/10-reasons-why-you-should-never-host-your-own-videos/